# Getting started with JSON in .net and mono

Tags: c#, .net, linux, json, mono

I would like to keep a custom configuration file for my app and JSON seems like an appropriate format*.

I know that there are JSON libraries for .NET, but I couldn't find a good comparative review of them. Also, my app needs to run on mono, so it's even harder to find out which library to use.

Here's what I've found:

- [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)
- [JSONSharp](http://code.google.com/p/jsonsharp/)

I remember reading that there is a built-in way to (de)serialize JSON as well, but I don't recall what it is.

What library would be easiest to use in mono on linux? Speed isn't critical, as the data will be small.

*Since the app runs on a headless linux box, I need to use the command line and would like to keep typing down to a minimum, so I ruled out XML. Also, I couldn't find any library to work with INF files, I'm not familiar with standard linux config file formats, and JSON is powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) can handle [JSON serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx) but it's not as powerful as some of the libraries for example it has no Parse method.

This might be a way to do it without libraries as I beleive Mono has implemented this class.

To get more readable JSON markup your class with attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeJsonyThing
{
    [DataMember(Name="my_element")]
    public string MyElement { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="my_nested_thing")]
    public object MyNestedThing { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: In my tests mono 2.8 has indeed implemented this class.

Comment: It looks like DCJS doesn't format the JSON in a very user-readable manner, but it works!

Comment: I wasn't referring to the naming scheme, I was talking about indentation (i.e. it doesn't use white space in the JSON output, which isn't very readable).

Comment: Oh, yes that is a problem. If you want to view it in Firefox though the JSON View extension will format it for you. Otherwise JSON.Net has a ToString method which can do Indented or non-indented.

Comment: Is there a way to use DataContractJsonSerializer with MonoTouch?  I have MonoDevelop 2.8.5 and it appears to only allow me to use .NET 2.0  reference assemblies when creating a MonoTouch library (which I would like to use from my MonoTouch app).  Is there a MonoTouch "binding" for .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Below is my implementation using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. It works in mono 2.8 on windows and ubuntu 9.04 (with mono 2.8 built from source). (And, of course, it works in .NET!) I've implemented some suggestions from [Best Practices: Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832)
. The file is stored in the same folder as the exe (not sure if I did that in the best manner, but it works in win and linux).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

using NLog;

[DataContract]
public class UserSettings : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    ExtensionDataObject IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int TestIntProp { get; set; }

    private string _testStringField;
}

public static class SettingsManager
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SettingsManager");

    private static UserSettings _settings;

    private static readonly string _path =
        Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(
                System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName),
            "settings.json");

    public static UserSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return _settings;
        }
    }

    public static void Load()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_path))
        {
            _logger.Trace("empty or null path");
            _settings = new UserSettings();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(_path))
                {
                    _logger.Trace("opened file");
                    _settings = SerializationExtensions.LoadJson<UserSettings>(stream);
                    _logger.Trace("deserialized file ok");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.TraceException("exception", e);
                if (e is InvalidCastException
                    || e is FileNotFoundException
                    || e is SerializationException
                    )
                {
                    _settings = new UserSettings();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Save()
    {
        if (File.Exists(_path))
        {
            string destFileName = _path + ".bak";
            if (File.Exists(destFileName))
            {
                File.Delete(destFileName);
            }
            File.Move(_path, destFileName);
        }
        using (var stream = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Settings.WriteJson(stream);
        }
    }
}

public static class SerializationExtensions
{
    public static T LoadJson<T>(Stream stream) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        object readObject = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        return (T)readObject;
    }

    public static void WriteJson<T>(this T value, Stream stream) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, value);
    }
}
```